# Ruby scan to match multiple words

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a code that parses through text files in a folder, and saves text around a certain search word.

However, I'm having trouble editing the code so that it works for multiple words at the same time. I do not want to loop the whole code because I want the results grouped for every text file instead of having it grouped for every search word.

Using `all_documents.scan("(word1|word2|word3)")` or regular expression variants that are similar does not seem to work.

```
    #helper
        def indices text, index, word
        padding = 20
        bottom_i = index - padding < 0 ? 0 : index - padding
        top_i = index + word.length + padding > text.length ? text.length : index +         word.length + padding
        return bottom_i, top_i
    end

    #script
    base_text = File.open("base.txt", 'w')
    Dir::mkdir("summaries") unless File.exists?("summaries")
    Dir.chdir("summaries")

    Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |textfile|
        whole_file = File.open(textfile, 'r').read
        puts "Currently summarizing " + textfile + "..."
        curr_i = 0
        str = nil
        whole_file.scan(/trail/).each do |match|
          if i_match = whole_file.index(match, curr_i)
            top_bottom = indices(whole_file, i_match, match)
            base_text.puts(whole_file[top_bottom[0]..top_bottom[1]] + " : " +         File.path(textfile))
            curr_i += i_match                     
          end
        end
        puts "Done summarizing " + textfile + "."
    end
    base_text.close
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`Regexp.union()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union) for that. It does exactly what you want.

In your code, it will become

```
...
whole_file.scan(Regexp.union(/trail/, /word1/, /word2/, /word3/)).each do |match|
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regexp.union`, but that is only generating sub-string matches. If you want to match complete words you need to do a bit more work. I'd use:

```
/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(%w[trail word1 word2 word3]).source })\b/
=> /\b(?:trail|word1|word2|word3)\b/
```

The resulting pattern will locate whole-words, ignoring any sub-strings:

```
foo = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(%w[trail word1 word2 word3]).source })\b/
# /\b(?:trail|word1|word2|word3)\b/

words = %w[trail word1 word2 word3]
words.join(' ').scan(foo)
# [
#     [0] "trail",
#     [1] "word1",
#     [2] "word2",
#     [3] "word3"
# ]

words.join.scan(foo)
# []

'trail word1word2 word3'.scan(foo)
# [
#     [0] "trail",
#     [1] "word3"
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better `scan` for anything that is a word (for example by `/[\w']+/`) and within the block of `scan`, check if `$&` matches any of the particular words. If `scan` happened to match a word that you are not interested in, then there is nothing wrong; just ignore it.